# Почему кнопка в JavaFX программе стала белой?

Tags: java, javafx, button, border

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с "плюсом", у этой кнопки пропадал border. Для этого я использую `act.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");`

Но выходит так, что при клике на кнопку её фон становится белым. По какой причине так происходит и как исправить?

[image: Если выставить -fx-border-color вручную, то всё в порядке. Border становится чёрного цвета.]

[image: После нажатия на кнопку с "плюсом".]

```
view.getAddActivityButton().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    Button act = view.getAddActivityButton();
    Button search = view.getAddSearchActivityButton();
                    view.getToolbarActivityPanel().getItems().remove(view.getAddActivityButton());
                    view.getToolbarActivityPanel().getItems().remove(view.getAddSearchActivityButton());

    TextField nameOfActivityTextField = new TextField();
                     view.getToolbarActivityPanel().getItems().add(0,newActivityHBox);
    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(0, act);
    newActivityHBox.setMargin(act,new Insets(0));
    act.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");
    nameOfActivityTextField.setMaxHeight(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(1,nameOfActivityTextField);
    newActivityHBox.getChildren().add(2, search);
/*...**/

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове `setStyle( "some text" )` заменяется весь стиль, а не только указанный параметр. Соответственно есть несколько способов обхода:

1) `act.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-background-color: black");`

2)

```
act.getStyleClass().add( "blackButton" );
//act.setId( "blackButton" );
```

```
.blackButton {
/*#blackButton {*/
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: white;
}
```

```
act.setStyle( "-fx-border-color: black;" );
```

3)

```
act.getStyleClass().add( "blackButton" );
```

```
.blackButton {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: white;
}
#blackBorder {
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

```
act.setId( "blackBorder" );
```

Comment: Спасибо, Andrey M, за подробный ответ.